# Add a conditional exception for a defined route

Tags: symfony, exception, routes

I want to deny the access for a defined route, to members that has a flag set to true in the database. So for example, I could add a starting condition to each action like:

```
    if ( $this->getUser()->HasPowers() ) {
        throw new AccessDeniedException;
    }
```

but there are too many actions and different controllers that match routes to be denied.

So I'm thinking about creating a new route(repeated) which will execute that action(deny if it has to do so), before any other action. Is it possible?

Comment: May be you can map your flags in DB to the existing mapping for ACL in Symfony[http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/acl_advanced.html#pre-authorization-decisions] then grant the users you want to the right privilages and filter the routing in security.yml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before filter should do the trick. Please read documentation: [Before filters with the kernel.controller Event](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/event_dispatcher/before_after_filters.html#before-filters-with-the-kernel-controller-event).

If you have a lot of routes/controllers or you don't like implement interfaces you could simply implement event listener for `kernel.request` event:

```
# app/config/config.yml
services:
    before_controller.listener:
        class: Acme\DemoBundle\EventListener\BeforeController
        calls:
            - [ setSecurityContext, [ "@security.context" ]]
            - [ setRouter, [ "@router" ]]
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request, method: onKernelRequest }
```

Next, implement listener:

```
# src\Acme\DemoBundle\EventListener;
namespace Acme\DemoBundle\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Routing\Router;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContext;

class BeforeController {
    protected $securityContext;

    protected $router;

    public function setRouter(Router $router){
        $this->router = $router;
    }

    public function setSecurityContext(SecurityContext $securityContext){
        $this->securityContext = $securityContext;
    }

    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event){
        if (!$this->securityContext->getToken()) {
            return;
        }

        $isUser = $this->securityContext->isGranted('ROLE_USER');

        if (!$isUser) {
            return;
        }

        $user = $this->securityContext->getToken()->getUser();

        if ($user->hasSomeFlag()) {
            $redirectUrl = $this->router->generate('some_route');
            $event->setResponse(new RedirectResponse($redirectUrl));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same kind of problem but I don't think a different route is the right solution. Have a look at this solution proposed by Matt Drollette:

https://matt.drollette.com/2012/06/calling-a-method-before-every-controller-action-in-symfony2/

It was a perfect fit for me. Basically you create a controller interface that calls a specific method before every other action, and then implement this interface in all the controllers where you need to check if the user hasPowers().