# an easier way of the redirect process according to state of user data in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.3

I want to add a process to redirect by the user data.
For example it is a point system.
It is forcibly redirect to static page if a user has not points.

I have on my mind that add process to construct function of common BaseController.

```
class BaseController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        if ($this->container->get('security.context')->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED')) {
            $user    = $this->container->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
            $manager = $this->container->get('doctrine')->getManager();

            if (! $manager->getRepository('MyUserBundle:User')->hasPoints($user))
                return new RedirectResponse($this->container->get('router')->generate('static_page_route'));
        }
    }
```

But I can't use a container.

> Error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object

point at issue:
1. How do I use user object at constructor.
2. Is there an easier way of the redirect process according to state of user data(like a points)?
   (The such as changing the role by state of user points though I still not know ACL details.)

---

#### add example:

```
public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event){
    if (!$this->securityContext->getToken()) {
        return;
    }

    $isUser = $this->securityContext->isGranted('ROLE_USER');

    if (!$isUser) {
        return;
    }

    $user    = $this->securityContext->getToken()->getUser();
    $request = $event->getRequest();
    $_route  = $request->attributes->get('_route');

    if (! $user->hasPoints() && $_route != 'static_page_route') {
        // exit; <= page rendering is done even if process exit.
        //          Redirect process be called after rendering?
        $redirectUrl = $this->router->generate('static_page_route');
        $event->setResponse(new RedirectResponse($redirectUrl));     // <= `The page isn't redirecting properly` error now.
    }
}
```

Comment: You will want to use a listener (probably on the CONTROLER event) for this sort of thing.  http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/event_listener.html

Comment: As I answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22380905/add-a-conditional-exception-for-a-defined-route/22381817#22381817 you could use `before filter`. Let me know if you need code example for your case.

Comment: Thank you for advices. Processing is also executed in the redirected location. So will access result in a loop? 
`The page isn't redirecting properly` has occurred. Should I branch on condition of route if static page is under the controller? (added example code above ... but doesn't work yet) And the another question is that page rendering is done even if process exit. Redirect process be called after rendering?

Comment: This `onKernelRequest` has been called several times?

Comment: Add an interface to controllers that need to be redirected (or one that doesn't) and then do a check on that in your listener. `if (!$controller[0] instanceof NoRedirectInterface) { \\ do redirct }`

Comment: I solved once after making 'HttpKernel::MASTER_REQUEST' check to BeforeController. It seem to work correctly. But should I branch on instance(action??) instead condition of route?  (added one solution code to the following)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution:

```
<?php

namespace My\ExampleBundle\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Routing\Router;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContext;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel;

class BeforeController {
    protected $securityContext;

    protected $router;

    public function setRouter(Router $router){
        $this->router = $router;
    }

    public function setSecurityContext(SecurityContext $securityContext){
        $this->securityContext = $securityContext;
    }

    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event){
        if (HttpKernel::MASTER_REQUEST != $event->getRequestType()) { return; }
        if (! $this->securityContext->getToken()) { return; }
        if (! $this->securityContext->isGranted('ROLE_USER')) { return; }

        $user    = $this->securityContext->getToken()->getUser();
        $request = $event->getRequest();
        $_route  = $request->attributes->get('_route');

        if (! $user->hasPoints() && $_route != 'static_page_route') {
            $redirectUrl = $this->router->generate('static_page_route');
            $event->setResponse(new RedirectResponse($redirectUrl));
        }
    }
}
```